# PHP code is just comment on my html

Tags: php

For some reason my code is just comment in my html.
I have tried using localhost/filename.html etc
and nothing seems to work...
Thank you!

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you've set up your server to process .html files as .php files, the filename needs to be .php (or one of the allowed php aliases)

Comment: do you have your extension of the file '.php' ?

Comment: Are you trying this on a LAMP/WAMP installation that is actually running PHP, otherwise nothing will happen, and parsing .html will take some .htaccess'ing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running apache you could add the following in your `.htaccess` file to process `.html` files as they were php:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Here are a couple of links further explaining the useage of `.htaccess` files:

1. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html
2. http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: in which directory can I find .htaccess?

Comment: Just create your own `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your `.html` file.